# Deployment Telerik.Web on IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, telerik

When I deployment asp.net 4.0 web site on IIS 6.0 server I have error:

```
[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Telerik.Web.RenderModesCache' threw an exception.]
Telerik.Web.RenderModesCache.GetViewDescriptors() +0
Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.GetViewScriptReference() +81
Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.GetScriptReferences() +80
Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.System.Web.UI.IScriptControl.GetScriptReferences() +13
System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.AddScriptReferenceForScriptControl(List`1 scriptReferences, IScriptControl scriptControl) +41
System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.AddScriptReferencesForScriptControls(List`1 scriptReferences) +92
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +129
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +122
System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +8897866
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2716
```

web.config has next configuration:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

 <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

With IIS Express 7.0 the web site working correctly.

What may be cause of the problem?

Comment: Is the application pool targetting .NET4 when you deploy?

Comment: Is .NET 4.0 even installed on the server running IIS 6.0?  Are these two separate servers running 6.0 and 7.0, or are you running them off of the same server?

Comment: rdmptn, yes, target was .net4

Comment: DanM, IIS 7 - it is development host, the code worked correct on his, but .. when the web site moved to production server (Win 2003, IIS 6) then i got error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not trying to use assemblies built against .NET 4.5 (Telerik provide those). If IIS6 is what your server has, it is, probably, Windows Server 2003 which does not have .NET 4.5. You should have your application(s) reference the .NET 4.0 builds of the Telerik assemblies (you can take them from the Bin40 folder of your installation).

As DanM said in the comments - make sure .NET 4.0 is installed if you are referencing the .NET 4 builds.

Comment: rdmptn, this is true.
After replace dll from Telerik (on .net 4.0) the site has earned.
Thank you.